# Is it possible to send an email when a checkbox is checked 'true' in Google Sheets to the email address listed on the same row as the checkbox?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how to automatically send out an email to the email address on the same row as the checkbox as soon as the checkbox is checked and marked as 'true'.

Then be able to have the email send something like: "Your ad is live."

[Here's a link to my sample spreadsheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o3JFTZvy1hV-IdP5PVWqZp-IPO8DDa-G8pK4e52Sf8E/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by making List of Selected email address from the List where checkbox is selected .

for this you have to create an ArrayList of String and when you click on send button you can add all email address from row where checkbox was selected and you can send email to those email address.

Comment: Do you have an example formula or script for that? I'm not an engineer, just spend a lot of time searching for how to's and answers to streamline my work. Thank you. Let's just say there is 1 email in the row where the checkbox occurs.